# js-datepicker date range end based on start

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I am using this datepicker https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker and have it working for the most part. However I would like to have the second date start and end dates based on what is selected in the start date.

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" name="message[dateStart][]" class='date date-start' placeholder="Start Date">

    <input type="text" name="message[dateEnd][]" class='date date-end' placeholder="End Date">
```

current javascript

```
// set date to 2 weeks from now calculated in milliseconds
var afterTwoWeeks = new Date(+new Date + 1209600000);

var pickerEnStart = datepicker('.date-start', {
  // dateSelected: new Date(2099, 0, 5)
  minDate: new Date(afterTwoWeeks),
  startDate: new Date(afterTwoWeeks),
  noWeekends: true,
  formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
    const value = date.toLocaleDateString()
    input.value = value // => '1/1/2099'
  }
})


var pickerEnEnd = datepicker('.date-end', {
  // dateSelected: new Date(2099, 0, 5)
  minDate: new Date(afterTwoWeeks),
  startDate: new Date(afterTwoWeeks),
  noWeekends: true,
  formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
    const value = date.toLocaleDateString()
    input.value = value // => '1/1/2099'
  }
})
```

I tried a couple of things but wasn't able to get the end date to start/end based on the start date selected date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work the way I'd expect it to work.

HTML

```
   <input type="text" name="message[dateStart][]" class='date date-start' placeholder="Start Date">

   <input type="text" name="message[dateEnd][]" class='date date-end' placeholder="End Date">  

   <input type="button" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
```

JS

```
var afterTwoWeeks = new Date(+new Date + 1209600000)

// none of this works well if we can't clear dates
var reset = document.getElementById('reset')
reset.onclick = function() {
  pickerEnStart.setDate()
  pickerEnEnd.setDate()
}

var pickerEnStart = datepicker('.date-start', {
  minDate: new Date(afterTwoWeeks),
  startDate: new Date(afterTwoWeeks),
  noWeekends: true,
  formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
    const value = date.toLocaleDateString()
    input.value = value 
  },
  id: 1,
  onSelect: (instance, date) => {
    // set the minimum date
    instance.setMin(date)
    // if end date not selected...
    if(!pickerEnEnd.dateSelected) { 
      // set the end date to force the calendar to display that month
      pickerEnEnd.setDate(new Date(date.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24), true)
      pickerEnEnd.firstTime = true
    }
  }
})

var pickerEnEnd = datepicker('.date-end', {
  minDate: new Date(afterTwoWeeks),
  startDate: new Date(afterTwoWeeks),
  noWeekends: true,
  formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
    const value = date.toLocaleDateString()
    input.value = value
  }, 
  id: 1,
  onSelect: (instance, date) => {
    instance.setMax(date)
  },
  onShow: function(instance) {
    // if this is the first time we're seeing this calendar...
    if (instance.firstTime) {
      // get rid of the end date we set to force it to this month
      instance.setDate();
      instance.firstTime = false;
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: I found a bug in this that you may want to explore. Set some dates a few months out, then reset. Now try to set a date, changing the month. The first date you set seems to be reflected in a "next month" somewhere. Probably just need to touch an additional variable on reset.

Comment: Now I need to set the maxDate on the second date picker to the date on the first picker + two weeks. I tried a number of things, but failed. Is this possible?

Comment: There are probably a lot of ways to do it, and mine is probably not the best. But, in the 2nd calendar, onShow, you can set a maxDate that is 2 weeks ahead of instance.minDate.

    instance.setMax(new Date(instance.minDate.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*14))

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much.